# Incorrect use of parent data widget

Tags: flutter, debugging, widget, parent

I am getting error of "incorrect use of parent data widget" in debug console while clicking these buttons specifically error shows when clicking  buttons. I am mentioning about the square buttons generated with List & Inkwell widget.

```
 class DetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DetailsPageState createState() => _DetailsPageState();
}

class _DetailsPageState extends State<DetailsPage> {
  int isselected = -1;
  int starvalue = 4;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: double.maxFinite,
        width: double.maxFinite,
        child: Stack(children: [
          Positioned(
              child: Container(
            width: double.maxFinite,
            height: 360,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage(
                      'assets/images/mountain.jpeg',
                    ),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover)),
          )),
          Positioned(
              top: 50,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ],
              )),
          Positioned(
              top: 270,
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 20, right:10),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(30))),
                height: 430,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        ApplargeText(
                          text: 'Yesomi',
                          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8),
                        ),
                        AppText(
                          text: '250',
                          size: 20,
                          color: AppColors.mainColor,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        const Icon(Icons.location_on),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 5,
                        ),
                        AppText(
                            text: 'USA, California',
                            color: AppColors.mainColor,
                            size: 15)
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Wrap(
                          children: List.generate(
                              5,
                              (index) => Icon(Icons.star,
                                  color: index < starvalue
                                      ? AppColors.starColor
                                      : AppColors.textColor2)),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 5,
                        ),
                        AppText(
                          text: '4.0',
                          size: 12,
                          color: AppColors.mainColor,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                    ),
                    ApplargeText(
                      text: 'people',
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8),
                      size: 25,
                    ),
                    AppText(
                      text: 'Number of people in your group',
                      size: 15,
                      color: Colors.black26,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Wrap(
                          children: List.generate(
                              5,
                              (index) => InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    isselected = index;
                                  });
                                },
                                child: SquareButton(
                                  size: 45,
                                  isIcon: false,
                                  iconn: Icons.search,
                                  text: (index + 1).toString(),
                                  textcolor: isselected == index
                                      ? Colors.white
                                      : Colors.orange,
                                  backgroundColor: isselected ==index
                                      ? Colors.black
                                      : Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ))),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                    ),
                    ApplargeText(
                      text: 'Description',
                      color: Colors.black,
                      size: 25,
                    ),
                    AppText(
                      text:
                          'Yesomi, the famed hill station of south India, is a romantic locale where natural beauty is everywhere to visit, explore and to enjoy.',
                      size: 12,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: 
 MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        SquareButton(
                          iconn: Icons.favorite_border,
                          size: 50,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                          isIcon: true,
                        ),
                        DefaultButtons(
                          width: 220,
                          text: 'Book now',
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ))
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

// Squarebutton widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:new_project/constants/appcolors.dart';

class SquareButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? text;
  final Color? textcolor;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  bool isIcon;
  final IconData? iconn;
  final Color? colorr;
double size;

  SquareButton({
    this.colorr,
    this.text,
    required this.size,
    this.textcolor,
    required this.backgroundColor,
    this.isIcon = false,
    this.iconn,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
        width: size,
        height: size,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            color: backgroundColor,
      border: Border.all(color: AppColors.mainColor, width:1.0)),
        child: isIcon == false
            ? Center(
                child: Text(
                text.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(
               color: isIcon == false ? textcolor : Colors.white),
              )): Icon(iconn));
  }
}
```

Comment: could you add `square button ` widget detail.

Comment: thanks for the  response,,  please have a look ,,now added

Comment: I'm not getting any errors with the codes you've provided. can you add code for `DefaultButtons`, `ApplargeText` and `AppText`?

Comment: oh thank you,, error solved.. issue with expanded widget.i used expanded widget in reusable  Defaultbutton.. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `Expanded` inside `Wrap` widget.

Comment: i tried, but same error exist... now i added complete code.. please have a look

Comment: issue was with expanded widget,,solved thank you